# Proof of linear mapping

Tags: linear-algebra

Question: let $M:X\rightarrow Y$ be a linear mapping. And $Z$ is a subspace of $Y$. Also, $A=\{ \vec{a} \in X:M(\vec{a}) \in Z \}$. Prove $A$ is a subspace of $X$.

This is my attempt. For the $0$ vector, $0A=\vec{0}$ because $X$ is linear. When adding any two elements from $A$, we have two instances $aA+bA$ is inside the domain of $X$, where $a, b\in \mathbb{R}$. And of course $aA$ would be inside $X$ as well. So we can conclude that $A$ is a subspace of $X$.

Is my attempt close to the answer?

Comment: What is the meaning of $0A$? Why is it equal to $\vec0$? What is the meaning of “we have two instances $aA+bA$ is inside the domain of $X$”?

Comment: You don't seem to have used the actual linear transformation $M$ anywhere in this proof, which is kind of necessary.

Comment: “$X$ is linear” and “domain of $X$”? What is that? To be clear, $X$ is a **vector space**! Your attempt doesn’t make much sense, please check again the definitions.

Comment: Ok....I will try this myself now